# In DRF, can we use other field than the primary field for a related model?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I am using Django Rest Framework for a small REST API. It's my first interaction with DRF and is pretty much all clear. But:

I have an Category model, for which I have an ID and an UUID field. The UUID field I want to use it for public exposed API.

What I basically want to achieve, is to be able to use Category.uuid instead of Category.id when I expose the API endpoint to the public (for all CRUD actions):

```py
    class CategoryModel(models.Model):

        uuid = models.UUIDField(default=uuid.uuid4, unique=True, editable=False)

    class ArticleModel(models.Model):
        user = models.ForeignKey(get_user_model(), on_delete=models.CASCADE, unique=False, related_name='articles')
        category = models.ForeignKey(CategoryModel, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='articles')


    # This serializer won't work as expected:

    class ArticleSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
        user = serializers.HiddenField(
            default=serializers.CurrentUserDefault()
        )

        category = serializers.CharField(source="category.uuid")

        class Meta:
            model = ArticleModel
            fields = ('category', 'user')
            validators = [
                UniqueTogetherValidator(
                    queryset=ArticleModel.objects.all(),
                    fields=('category', 'user'),
                    message=_('You have already added an article in this category')
                )
            ]
```

I have also tried to use a custom serializer, exposing only the uuid field, but without success.

**Please do not suggest to use uuid as primary key in CategoryModel. I don't want to do that!**

Test post data:

```
{
    category: "328d9185-02ae-4963-88a5-03ef67421697"
}
```

Posting the above data, I would expect to create an article having the `category.uuid = 328d9185-02ae-4963-88a5-03ef67421697` and `user = current authenticated user`.

**Edit**

Error message: {"category":["Incorrect type. Expected pk value, received str."]}

Comment: So what is the error you get with the current code? 'without success' isn't really enough info to go by

Comment: I am sorry. I thought i added the error message. I will edit the question. It

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the [SlugRelatedField](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/relations/#slugrelatedfield) in your serializer like this:

```
category = serializers.SlugRelatedField(slug_field='uuid', queryset=CategoryModel.objects.all())
```

Comment: Thank you @Ken4scholars. I saw that "SlugRelatedField may be used to represent the target of the relationship using a field on the target." but didn't imagine I can use it this way. Is this a common approach in DRF ? I am asking because I want to accept your answer, but I don't want to others to develop a bad habit. Thanks.

Comment: For your use case, yes.

Comment: Perfect. Thank you !

Comment: It matches exactly your use case and it's the correct answer